# Ocra error "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" in Ocra when compiling

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, ocra, ruby2d

"No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users//OneDrive/Desktop/ruby/fiber.so (Errno::ENOENT)" keeps getting thrown by Ocra when I try to compile my app into an exe.
I've used fixes mentioned by others but none of them work, likely because most of them are for an older version of Ruby.
I'm using Ruby2d and I include it in my command:
`ocra --verbose move.rb --no-dep-run --gem-minimal=ruby2d`

Comment: I put fiber.so into my mingw directory for ruby and it worked

Comment: Consider posting the proposed answer as an answer to the question (it's currently posted as a comment and was previously edited into the question) or upvoting / recommending an existing answer if it resolves the issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.